# form is not validating because of date field is not a valid format

Tags: python, django, django-forms

Form is not validating because of date field is not a valid format can any one help me.

#### settings.py

```
USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True

API = 'Apache-HttpClient'

ACCEPTABLE_FORMATS = ['%Y-%m-%d',       # '2006-10-25'
                      '%d-%m-%Y',       # '25-10-2006'
                      '%d/%m/%Y',       # '25/10/2006'
                      '%d/%m/%y']       # '25/10/06'
```

#### models.py

```
class SaveTrip(models.Model):
    """storing user saving trips
    """
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    From = models.CharField(max_length=32) 
    to = models.CharField(max_length=32)
    from_date = models.DateField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False)
    to_date = models.DateField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False)
    choice = models.CharField(max_length=32, null=True, blank=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "User Saved Trips"

    def get_trip(self):
        return "%s -> %s" % (self.From, self.to)

    def __unicode__(self): # __str__ on Python 3
        return self.get_trip()
```

#### Forms.py

```
class SaveTripForm(forms.Form):
    From = forms.CharField(max_length=32)
    to = forms.CharField(max_length=32)
    from_date = forms.DateField(input_formats=ACCEPTABLE_FORMATS)
    to_date = forms.DateField(input_formats=ACCEPTABLE_FORMATS)
    choice = forms.CharField(max_length=32, required=False)

    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = self.cleaned_data

        From = cleaned_data.get("From")
        to = cleaned_data.get("to")
        from_date = cleaned_data.get("from_date")
        to_date = cleaned_data.get("to_date")
        choice = cleaned_data.get("choice")
        return cleaned_data
```

#### shell

```
python manage.py shell
Python 2.7.11 (v2.7.11:6d1b6a68f775, Dec  5 2015, 20:32:19) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
(InteractiveConsole)
>>> a = {u'From':[u'Bangalore'], u'userid':[u'50'], u'choice':[u'(4,)'], u'to':[u'Goa'], u'from_date':[u'2016-10-20'], u'to_date':[u'2016-10-23']}
>>> from uprofile.forms import SaveTripForm
>>> abc = SaveTripForm(a)
>>> abc.is_valid()
False
>>> abc.errors
{'from_date': [u'Enter a valid date.'], 'to_date': [u'Enter a valid date.']}
>>> abc.cleaned_data
{'to': u"[u'Goa']", 'From': u"[u'Bangalore']", 'choice': u"[u'(4,)']"}
>>>
```

Comment: Why do you provide field values as tuples in `a` I wonder? The date format looks ok, I wonder if anything in your settings messes it up.

Comment: if post data values are in unicode form in valid. but actually django post data values are in list type.
For more information find in link
https://ghostbin.com/paste/ets2z

Answer (score 0):

When you look at a query dict (e.g. `request.POST`), you will see lists, because HTML forms can submit multiple values for the same key.

However, when you construct the data dictionary manually, you should use strings instead of lists.

```
a = {u'From': 'Bangalore', u'userid': '50', u'choice':'(4,)', u'to':'Goa', u'from_date':'2016-10-20', u'to_date':'2016-10-23'}
abc = SaveTripForm(a)
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually the Problem with the `request.POST` data.
Form is not validating because of post data value are in LIST.
For this issue we can achieve like this
`abc = SaveTripForm(a.dict())`

## **Shell**

```
python manage.py shell
Python 2.7.11 (v2.7.11:6d1b6a68f775, Dec  5 2015, 20:32:19) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
(InteractiveConsole)
>>> a = {u'From':[u'Bangalore'], u'userid':[u'50'], u'choice':[u'(4,)'], u'to':[u'Goa'], u'from_date':[u'2016-10-20'], u'to_date':[u'2016-10-23']}
>>> from uprofile.forms import SaveTripForm
>>> abc = SaveTripForm(a.dict())
>>> abc.is_valid()
True
>>> abc.errors
{}
>>>
```