# How can we convert Django Post QueryDict

Tags: python, django

**Current QueryDict**

> {u'From': [u'Bangalore'], u'userid': [u'50'], u'choice': [u'(4,)'], u'to': [u'Goa'], u'from_date': [u'2016-11-10'], u'to_date': [u'2016-12-23']}

**Required QueryDict**

> {u'From': u'Bangalore', u'userid': u'50', u'choice': u'(4,)', u'to': u'Goa', u'from_date': u'2016-11-10', u'to_date': u'2016-12-23'}

Comment: Can you write an example how you get this queryset?

Comment: In django querysets are defined like that but you can access the value by using queryset.get(key). That will give you the value and not the list.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because SO is not a code-writing service.

Comment: I don't think you really need to do this conversion. Django forms can handle the first query dict just fine. The problem is if you use a regular dictionary with lists as values. See my answer to [your other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36690433/form-is-not-validating-because-of-date-field-is-not-a-valid-format).

Comment: @Lucas03 Its not a queryset. It is post data parameters.

Comment: @Aquiles Its not a queryset

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `QueryDict` class has a [`dict()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/request-response/#django.http.QueryDict.dict) method that will return a regular dictionary. For example:

```
request.POST.dict()
```

However, it's not clear why you would need to do this. Note that if one of the values lists contains multiple items, then only the last item will be returned when you convert it to a dict.

Comment: Thanks @Alasdair
Almost your answer is good, but your code is won't work. to achieve this `data = request.POST`
`data.dict()`
Because request.POST is Immutable.

Comment: I'm not sure what you think doesn't work in my answer. As I said, the `dict()` method returns a dictionary. It's up to you to assign that to a variable if required.

Comment: yes it works. but we need to write like this`(request.POST).dict()`

Comment: `(request.POST).dict()` works exactly the same as `request.POST.dict()`.